# ¿Como eliminar un registro de una base de datos en java?

Tags: java

cree una base de datos en java de una empresa, y necesito desde java poder eliminarlo sin ir al mysql. Cree un JButton y al presionarlo tendría que eliminar el registro de mi tabla empresa y por consiguiente de la base de datos en mysql

Comment: Puedes buscar información sobre JDBC. Se trata de una librería bastante usada para el acceso a datos.

Answer (score 2):

Te diría que pongas el código para tener una referencia, si usas un botón para eliminarlo en tu aplicación un código "parecido" seria este, donde estableces conexión y haces una consulta de datos en x tabla, si los datos coinciden lo elimina:

```
Pool metodospool = new Pool();    

public void Eliminar(String idcontacto, String valor, String filtro, JTable tablacontactos){

int confirmar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Esta seguro que desea eliminar el registro?");

if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION==confirmar) { 

   Connection conexion = null;

 try { 
        conexion = metodospool.dataSource.getConnection();
        String Ssql = "DELETE FROM contacto "
                    + "WHERE id_contacto = ?";

        PreparedStatement prest = conexion.prepareStatement(Ssql); 

        prest.setString(1, idcontacto);

        if(prest.executeUpdate()>0){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El registro ha sido eliminado exitosamente", 
                                              "Operación Exitosa", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                //Opcional
                Buscar(valor, filtro, tablacontactos); 
                Limpiar();
         }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido eliminar el registro\n"
                + "Inténtelo nuevamente.", "Error en la operación", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

   } catch(SQLException error){

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido eliminar el registro\n Inténtelo nuevamente.\n"
                                    + "Error: "+error, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

   }finally{


        if(conexion!=null){

            try {

                 conexion.close();

            } catch (SQLException error2) {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar cerrar la conexión.\n Error: "+error2, 
                                                   "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

        }       


   }
}

}


MetodosBD metodosbd = new MetodosBD();
private void btnEliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

   if(idcontacto.isEmpty()){

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay datos para eliminar.\n"
       + "Por favor, seleccione un registro de la tabla.", "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

   }else{

        metodosbd.Eliminar(idcontacto, txtValorbusqueda.getText(), cboxFiltro.getSelectedItem().toString(), tblDatos); // Los datos a eliminar

   }
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda ya que sin ver el código lo pongo por intuición.

Answer (score 0):

para poder realizar la eliminacion de un registro en base de datos (y recién estas aprendiendo persistencia con java) te recomiendo JDBC. A continuación te voy a pasar unos ejemplos de como implementarla (doy por hecho que ya sabes generar una conexion a la misma asi que solamente presentaré un metodo de delete).

```
 static final String DELETE = "DELETE FROM CONTACTOS WHERE NOMBRE = ?";

 public void eliminarContacto(String c) {
        try(Connection con = Singleton_ConexionDB.getConexionClass().getConexionDB();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(DELETE);){

        stmt.setString(1, c.toUpperCase());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        }catch(SQLException se){
        se.getMessage();
        }
}
```

En el ejemplo vemos como con el **try with resources** (que manejará el cierre de recursos de manera automática) traigo mi instancia de conexión desde otra clase (puedes hacerlo ahí mismo pero es muy recomendado manejarla como clase aparte y patrón singleton).

Después con **PreparedStatement** indico la **query** (en este caso delete) y más tarde la ejecuto con `executeUpdate()` .

En el ejemplo brindado a la consulta le agregue la clausula where para borrar un registro por nombre, de allí que antes de el `executeUpdate()` hago un `setString(1, c.toUpperCase());`